# ICC vs GCC - Optimization and CPU architecture

Tags: gcc, x86, x86-64, compiler-optimization, icc

I'm interested in knowing how GCC differs from Intel's ICC in terms of the optimization levels and catering to specific processor architecture. I'm using GCC 4.1.2 20070626 and ICC v11.1 for Linux.

How does ICC's optimization levels (O1 to O3) differ from GCC, if they differ at all?

The ICC is able to cater specifically to different architectures (IA-32, intel64 and IA-64). I've read that GCC has the `-march` compiler option which I think is similar, but I can't find a list of the options to use. I'm using Intel Xeon X5570, which is 64-bit. Are there any other GCC compiler options I could use that would cater my applications for 64-bit Intel CPUs?

Answer (score 2):

`icc -O2 -unroll2` is roughly equivalent to `gcc -O3 -ffast-math -fno-cx-limited-range -funroll-loops --param max-unroll-times=2`
gcc -O1 doesn't enable SIMD auto-vectorization for either compiler, so there is less difference.

ICC with no options defaults to optimization enabled and [`-fp-model=fast=1`](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/documentation/cpp-compiler-developer-guide-and-reference/top/compiler-reference/compiler-options/compiler-option-details/floating-point-options/fp-model-fp.html) (a bit less aggressive than `gcc -ffast-math`), but GCC defaults to `-O0`.  (Also `-fno-fast-math` even with `gcc -O3`.  Only `gcc -Ofast` enables fast-math like the ICC default.)

`-march=native` is the GCC option to use the full instruction set of the build machine.  ICC supports `-march=native` as equivalent to its own `-xHost` option.  At the time of this question, that ICC option may have worked only for Intel CPUs.

GCC can be configured with either `-m64` or `-m32` as the default, but the same compiler can compile binaries of either bitness.  ICC provides separately built compilers to target 64-bit or 32-bit mode;  icc expects you to choose, if both are installed, by sourcing their path setting script.

Comment: Are you sure about `-m32` requiring separate binaries for ICC?  It's certainly not true for GCC, the same `gcc` front-end runs the same `/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/11.1.0/cc1` C compiler proper, just with different options.  (And links different CRT .o files when linking.)  I fixed your answer's claim about that for GCC, but I'm not totally sure of ICC so I left that claim in.  But on https://godbolt.org/z/ezMKcaTc3 `-m32` just works as an option to "x86-64 ICC 2021.5.0" to make 32-bit asm so I'm skeptical.  (The rest of this answer looks right, though, +1)

Answer (score 1):

See section 3.17.15 in the GCC manual, [ie386 and x86-64 Options](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/i386-and-x86_002d64-Options.html#i386-and-x86_002d64-Options) for the full list and description of all the options applicable to those architectures (IA-64 is Itanium, and it's unlikely you have one of those).

The most important options in this context are:

- `-m64` Generate 64-bit code;
- `-march=` Generate instructions for a specific CPU type; and
- `-mtune=` Tune the code for a specific CPU type.

Comment: Also `-O3` and `-ffast-math` are important for GCC, to be similar to the ICC default (optimize with auto-vectorization and `-fp-model=fast=1` - https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/documentation/cpp-compiler-developer-guide-and-reference/top/compiler-reference/compiler-options/compiler-option-details/floating-point-options/fp-model-fp.html)